# LSTM in Pytorch

Tags: python, neural-network, deep-learning, lstm, pytorch

I'm new to PyTorch. I came across some this [GitHub repository (link to full code example)](https://github.com/yunjey/pytorch-tutorial/blob/master/tutorials/02-intermediate/recurrent_neural_network/main.py#L38-L56) containing various different examples.

There is also an example about LSTMs, this is the Network class:

```python
# RNN Model (Many-to-One)
class RNN(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, num_classes):
        super(RNN, self).__init__()
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.num_layers = num_layers
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.fc = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Set initial states 
        h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) 
        c0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))

        # Forward propagate RNN
        out, _ = self.lstm(x, (h0, c0))  

        # Decode hidden state of last time step
        out = self.fc(out[:, -1, :])  
        return out
```

So my question is about the following lines:

```python
h0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size)) 
c0 = Variable(torch.zeros(self.num_layers, x.size(0), self.hidden_size))
```

As far as I understand it, `forward()` is called for every training example. But this would mean, that the hidden state and cell state would be resettet i.e. replaced with a matrix of zeros on every training example.

The names `h0` and `c0` indicate that this is only the hidden/cell state at t=0, but why then are theses zeros matrices handed over to the lstm with every training example?

Even if they are just ignored after the first call, it would not be a very nice solution.

When testing the code it states an accuracy of 97% on the MNIST set, so it seems to work this way, but it doesn't make sense to me.

Hope someone can help me out with this.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Obviously I was on the wrong track with this. I was confusing hidden units and hidden/cell state.
Only the hidden units in the LSTM are trained during the training step. Cell state and hidden state are resetet at the beginning of every sequence. So it just makes sense that it is programmed this way.

Sorry for this..